# How to give sftp access to sub-directory only not to parent

Tags: files, permissions, directory, sftp

I want to give SFTP access to user `tom` for directory `/var/www/html/my_project/`. while I don't want to give any SFTP access to directory `/var/www/html/`.

currently `/var/www/html/my_project/` and `/var/www/html/` is owned by apache user.I need to give access only to  `/var/www/html/my_project/` directory for both user tom as well as apache.

Once access is given tom can access all the directories which are under /var/www/html/my_project/.

Please help me I am struggling since a long time.

Comment: What do you mean by access? read? write? both?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel yes read+write both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like the following in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Match User tom
ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/my_project/
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then, make sure tom has permission to access that directory.  This can be tricky as `tom` would need at least 'x' (execute) permissions for all directories above the intended directory.  /var/www/html/ is usually accessible to everyone in most flavors of Linux/Unix.

I would probably make the `my_project` directory owned by `tom`, and have tom in the apache group.  If apache is running as apache:apache (user:group), the following should work for that:

From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/

```
# usermod -a -G apache tom
```

Make whole `my_project` directory owned by user `tom` and group `apache`.

```
# chown -R tom:apache /var/www/html/my_project/
```

Make whole `my_project` directory fully writable to `tom`, and readable/executable to the `apache` group.

```
# chmod -R 750 /var/www/html/my_project/
```

Note: Any files that `tom` creates will be owned by tom's user and his default group.  The above example adds `tom` to the group `apache`, but doesn't make `apache` his default group.  This means the apache server won't have access to new files.  To fix that, make `apache` be `tom`'s default group by `useradd -g apache tom`.

Comment: So how would you use that to restrict a user to a directory tree?

Comment: The `ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts/website.com/` restricts the user to the `/var/www/vhosts/website.com/` directory.  When they SFTP in, that is their root, `/`.

Comment: What user? If this is a file under `/etc`, it applies to all users.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The user is defined in `Match group website_ftpuser`.

Comment: More can be found at tutorials like http://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze -- starting at step 3.

Comment: OK, you do understand my question. The original question concerns a user "tom". `Match group website_ftpuser` looks like something that would match all FTP users. How do you make the chroot apply to a single user?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You must have missed the first thing in my response, "I use something like the following in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file".

Comment: No, I saw that, and so I understand that this solves some problem that you have. I'm trying to figure out what it has to do with *this* question.

Comment: I think you just wanted a better answer -- could have just asked for that ;).  My answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe chroot the user tom in the `/var/www/html/my_project/` by correctely configure your SFTP server. The access from apache will be allowed, and tom can't go up its chroot dir.

To help you more, you need to say what SFTP server you are using.